# Is there a software or programming method for document (PDF) separation?

Tags: pdf

Is there a software for separating multiple PDF documents? Maybe with some sort of AI? For instance, I have multiple scanned PDFs and in each PDF I have tons of different documents inserted together. The trouble it is in finding where a new document starts and ends in each PDF, otherwise I could very easily do it with a bit of programming. Also, since I have multiple PDFs, this task done by 'hand' (selecting pages where each document starts and ends) it is quite difficult and it is really not an option.

So, do you guys have a suggestion or an alternative option? Maybe some PDF plugin? Also, I'm not entirely sure this is the correct stackexchange for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Probability of such existing is very low.

It very unlikely that you or anybody esle have time to teach a AI system to do this because thet would mean youd have to have a buch of training data to do it. Which most likely is as time consuming to get as categorizing your dataset properly to begin with. But here it really depends on the dataset it MIGHT be easy.

It is also a very small market which means its unlikely to be done by somebody else.

But splitting if the page is known is obviously easy. You may also luck out, if the pages arent OCR:ed and they are suffciently simimilar then you might find other clues like page numbers that could make this relatively straightforward.

Comment: The are OCR'd but poorly. I'm having trouble in constructing the dataset that I (might) need in order to perform some training. I also asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321238/extracting-character-font-size-from-pdf-files-with-r A paper that I am judging to be useful it is this one: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7955/9bc8cff7f81699a63e8c43548753041cd920.pdf